# Count the number of words in dictionary from a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Given a list:

`lst = ['apple', 'orange', 'pears', 'pears', 'banana']`

and a dictionary

`dict = {'orange': 4, 'apple':2, 'pears': 1}`

if a string from the list already exist in dict update the value else add a new key and its counting.

result:

`dict = {'orange' = 5, 'apple':3, 'pears':3, 'banana':1}`

I tried:

```
count = 0
for string on lst:
    if string in dict.keys():
        for num in dict:
            count = count + num
            num = count
```

I don't know how to continue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer was almost correct:

```
for string in lst:
    if string in dict.keys():
        dict[string] += 1
    else:
        dict[string] = 1
```

This is assuming that a string you haven't seen yet starts with a value of 1, which seems to be the case given your output.

You could also remove the .keys(), as python will automatically check in the keys for the values you are looping on, hence:

```
for string in lst:
    if string in dict:
        dict[string] += 1
    else:
        dict[string] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

>>> lst = ['apple', 'orange', 'pears', 'pears', 'banana']
>>> d = {'orange': 4, 'apple':2, 'pears': 1}

>>> count = Counter(d)
>>> count
Counter({'orange': 4, 'apple': 2, 'pears': 1})
>>> count += Counter(lst)
>>> count
Counter({'orange': 5, 'pears': 3, 'apple': 3, 'banana': 1})
```

Comment: I know this is off topic, but how did it place `pears` ahead of `apple`?

Comment: I don't think there is a need of `Counter(d)`, because `d` itself is a dictionary of counts and you can access with `d.get()`.

Comment: @Austin Yes but then you still have to write the update logic yourself. `Counter` was made to specifically solve this exact problem

Comment: @TeraBaapBC Dictionaries in Python have no inherent order, so there is no concept of one key being "ahead" of another

Comment: Isn't using `d.get(item, 0)` and adding it with `Counter()` of that item in list more efficient than doing `Counter()` twice?

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done with simple list looping and `dict.get` method, though other efficient method exist.

```
lst = ['apple', 'orange', 'pears', 'pears', 'banana']
dict = {'orange': 4, 'apple':2, 'pears': 1}

for st in lst:
     dict[st] = dict.get(st,0)+1

dict
{'orange': 5, 'apple': 3, 'pears': 3, 'banana': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before extending, there is a typo in line 2, which should be for string **in** list.

This is my suggested solution.  As you iterate through the list, check each entry to see if it is a key in the dictionary (as you have already done).  If it is, the dict[string] will be the number value paired with that key and you can add one to it.  If not, then you can add the string as a new key with a value of 1.

```
# original data
lst = ['apple', 'orange', 'pears', 'pears', 'banana']  
dict = {'orange': 4, 'apple':2, 'pears': 1}

# iterate through lst and add 1 to each corresponding key value
for string in lst:
    if string in dict.keys():
        #  increment count for a found key 
        #  which can be accessed in dict[string] - no need for num
        count = int(dict[string])
        dict[string] = count + 1
    else:
        # add new key and a count of 1 to dict
        dict[string] = 1
```